# Замена слов в Java

Tags: java

Есть строка например "1 qqq    4 aaa  2" и есть лист {aaa, qqq}. Нужно заменить все слова(сост из букв) на слова из листа. Т.е. Должно получиться "1 aaa    4 qqq  2". Пыталась

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str, " ");
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
        tmp = tokenizer.nextToken();
        if(tmp.matches("^[a-z]+$"))
            newStr = newStr.replaceFirst(tmp, words.get(l++));
    }
```

Но оно замененное слово заменяет обратно и выводит все ту же строку.

Comment: В списке может быть больше 2 элементов?

Comment: @LEQADA Да. Но кол-во слов всегда совпадает. Список - все слова в строке отсортированные по алфавиту.

Comment: Совпадает с чем? Что будет, если список `{"a","b","c"}`, а строка `"2 b 1 a c"`?

Comment: @LEQADA  - `"2 a 1 b c"`

Comment: @LEQADA Совпадает с тем, что нужно заменить. Т.е. в Вашем примере ответ должен быть "2 a 1 b c"

Comment: то есть надо расставить слова в тексте по алфавиту?

Comment: @Igor, я так понял, что алфавитом в данном случае является список. В каком порядке элементы в списке - в том и должны быть в строке.

Comment: @Igor Да. Слова состоящие только из букв расставить по алфавиту оставляя остальные без изменений. Кол-во пробелов также не должно изменяться.

Comment: @LEQADA - да. Просто она в комментарии сказала, что " Список - все слова в строке отсортированные по алфавиту."

Comment: @Мари - пока не вижу дырок, правда, кода недостаточно для компиляции. Попробуйте, выводить `newStr` после каждой замены.

Comment: @Igor Код работает, проблема в том, что он заменяет qqq на aaa, но потом, когда нужно заменить aaa на qqq, он заменяет то слово, которое только что вставил и на выходе та же строка... Ой, запутано все как...

Comment: @Мари - А, ну да. Придется Вам вручную это делать. `Substring` в java есть?

Comment: @Igor Есть, но я пыталась вручную и что-то запуталась совсем. Не могу сообразить как

Comment: Предлагаю порубить всю строку на куски - слова и то, что между ними. В получившемся списке заменить слова на сортированые слова, и склеить все обратно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочий вариант:

```
    String str = "1 qqq 4 aaa 2";
    String[] words = {"aaa", "qqq"};
    int wordIndex = 0;
    String newStr = "";

    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str, " ", true);
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
        String tmp = tokenizer.nextToken();
        if(tmp.matches("^[a-z]+$")) {
            newStr += words[wordIndex++];
        } else {
            newStr += tmp;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(newStr);
```

Comment: Не сохраняет кол-во пробелов как в исходной строке

Comment: Сейчас поправлю

Comment: Т.е. строка на выходе должна иметь столько же пробелов, сколько в начальной

Comment: Ну да, так и работает, проверьте